# Prove whether this number is or is not prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Is the number 2438100000001 composite or prime?

Please first give a hint if you already know the answer.thanks!

Comment: There is one prime factor between $70$ and $80.$

Comment: How do we know this?

Comment: The number splits into $4$ prime factors. The least one is Dr.Sheldon Cooper's favorite number.

Comment: @peter Well I watch The Big Bang Theory a lot but I seriously forgot his favorite number so gimme a clue maybe?

Comment: The number is a palindrom in binary notation. And the mirror-number is also a prime.

Comment: And the positions in the prime count of the two primes are also mirror-numbers.

Comment: Do you need more hints ? Or shall I solve ?

Comment: I got it it's 73 but how did you come up with that?

Comment: To be honest, I did not calculate it by hand ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Hint 1:** Notice that $243$ and $81$ are powers of $3$, so the number has the form
$$3^5\cdot10^{10}+3^4\cdot10^8+1$$

**Hint 2:** $x^5+x^4+1$ is reducible.

**Hint 3:** $x^5+x^4+1=(x^5+x^4+x^3)+(1-x^3)$.

Comment: well I cannot reduce the polynomial above guess I'm really dumb after all ...

Comment: sorry I really am not into what you're saying.I'm not that much advanced in maths I was wondering for a bit more simplified solution.

Comment: @FuriousMathematician: What part of the above solution do you find advanced? Perhaps you do not like the word "reducible" (this is not usually expressed this way until one starts studying polynomial rings). If that is the case, simply replace the offending word with "factors".

Comment: @user2345215: If that is the case, perhaps you could indicate how to find integer factorizations of polynomials by trial and error. Namely, it is either degree 1 * degree 4 or degree 2 * degree 3, the leading coefficients can be assumed to be 1, the constant terms are either both 1 or both -1, etc. One gets a system of equations in terms of the coefficients that is easily solvable.

Answer (score 6):

[You already figured out the answer, so even though this is more than a hint, I hope I’m not giving anything away.]

If you notice the powers of $3$ hiding ($243$ and $81$), you may think to rewrite this big number as $$2438100000001=3^5\cdot10^{10}+3^4\cdot10^8+1.$$ Then you might write  $$2438100000001=300^5+300^4+1.$$ You might not see how to factor this, but you can look for a pattern for factoring similar expressions with smaller numbers than $300$.

$$\begin{align}
&1^5+1^4+1& =\quad&3& =\quad&\color{blue}3\cdot 1\\
&2^5+2^4+1& =\quad&49& =\quad&\color{blue}7\cdot 7\\
&3^5+3^4+1& =\quad&325& =\quad&\color{blue}{13}\cdot 25\\
&4^5+4^4+1& =\quad&1281& =\quad&\color{blue}{21}\cdot 61\\
&5^5+5^4+1& =\quad&3751& =\quad&\color{blue}{31}\cdot 341\\
&\cdots\\
&300^5+300^4+1& =\quad& 2438100000001& =\quad& ?\cdot ?\\
\end{align}$$

Notice that if you happen to factor these numbers the way I show, the differences between the first factors form an arithmetic sequence. The first factors are $\color{blue}3, \color{blue}3+\color{red}4=\color{blue}7, \color{blue}7+\color{red}6=\color{blue}{13}, \color{blue}{13}+\color{red}8=\color{blue}{21}, \color{blue}{21}+\color{red}{10}=\color{blue}{31},\dots$ (You have to play with the factorizations to see this — the factor I wrote first isn’t always the smallest prime factor, or even a prime, so you have to play around.)

When a sequence of numbers has differences that are an arithmetic sequence, there’s a formula for that sequence using multiples of $n^2$, $n$, and constants. If you knew that, you’d notice that the sequence $(3,7,13,21,31,\dots)$ is $(1^2+2,2^2+3,3^2+4,4^2+5, 5^2+6,\dots)$, and you might guess that $90301=300^2+301$ is a factor of your original number.

And you would be right.

In somewhat less time, you could try prime factors and find $73$, but finding the factor $90301$ (which is $73\cdot1237$) by hand is more interesting!

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question: $2438100000001$ is a composite number.

$2438100000001 = 73 \dot\  829 \dot\  1237 \dot \  32569$

Answer (score -2):

**Hint:** Multiply 1025473 by 2377537. Neither of these two numbers is prime, but you should easily be able to factor them with the help of an ordinary scientific calculator and a list of small primes.

**EDIT:** You said

> Please first give a hint if you already know the answer.

That's exactly what I'm doing by showing you that 2438100000001 is divisible by numbers other than 1 and itself. I already know the answer because this number, as forbidding as it may look, it's quite small compared to the numbers computers are routinely factoring these days. If you don't have Mathematica, try putting this question to Wolfram Alpha: "factor 2438100000001." With a decent Internet connection, it should give you the answer after only a very short wait.